# Eastern Europeans integration in the USA politics

Tags: united-states, europe

How successful were and are the Eastern Europeans and their descendants in the USA politics?

Are they pretty well (according to the percent they represent in the USA demographics) represented in legislatures?

Is there any list of Eastern European American politicians?

Wikipedia: [American people of Eastern European descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:American_people_of_Eastern_European_descent)

Comment: After a generation or two, most people really don't care.  After three, only the genealogy-obsessed even know.

Comment: To get an answer I suggest that you clearly define your terms.  What, specifically, do you mean by "Eastern European American" since NOBODY I know self identifies by that category.

Comment: I would also add that how you titled your post and the actual question seem to differ. The title seems as though you are asking about the alleged hacking attempts of US voting. Secondly, as Americans you typically loose that view point pretty quickly faster than probably even @jamesqf suggests. Being that I am 3rd generation from a heritage that comes from the baltics my Grandfather and Grandmother thought of themselves as Americans not Eastern Europeans in America. So if they were elected they would no longer be "Europeans" in politics they would be American's in politics.

Comment: I think @jamesqf has it pretty much correct. When I looked over those lists I provided, I found a lot of names of powerful people who I knew, but had no idea they had that background. Sanders was interesting enough to throw into the answer, but the rest nobody really even cares enough to bring up, so its not well-known. Pretty much **everyone** in the USA has some kind of immigrant background (even [Ben Nighthorse Campbell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Nighthorse_Campbell#Early_life)'s mother was born in Portugal)

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. I provided a link to an American Eastern Europeans category on Wikipedia. Can anyone suggest a better name for the title of the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite successful, in the cases where they could muster the talent and connections required.

The person who leaps to mind here is Dan Rostenkowsi, who for a decade when I was a kid was arguably the most powerful man in Washington as Chair of the [House Ways and Means Committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Committee_on_Ways_and_Means)<sup>*</sup>. His Grandfather [immigrated from Tuchola, Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Rostenkowski#Early_life_and_political_beginnings), and his father was an Alderman in Chicago. That's essentially 1st generation Polish-American going straight into local politics, and 2nd into national.

Other notables who were actual immigrants are Carter's National Security Advisor [Zbignew Brzezinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zbigniew_Brzezinski) (Warsaw), and Clinton's State Department head [Madeline Albright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeleine_Albright) (Prague). Bernie Sanders' father was born in Poland as well.

Wikipedia has long lists of [US politicians of Polish Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Polish_Americans#Politics) and [Czech descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Czech_Americans#Government_.26_politics), a smaller one for those of [Serbian descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Serbian_Americans#Politicians), and an incomplete list for [Russian descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_Americans#Politics).

<sup>* - This House committee was parodied in Eddie Murphy's movie [Distinguished Gentleman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Distinguished_Gentleman) as "The Power Committee". Its head met roughly the same end as Rostenkowski.</sup>

Comment: You also have to consider that an eastern European family name doesn't necessarily mean a large share of eastern European ancestry.  Could be 1/2 the first generation, 1/4th for 1 grandparent, 1/8 for a great-grandparent, and so on.

Comment: @jamesqf - True, which is why I listed the actual immigrant parantage for everyone called out in my answer. Similarly, a non-eastern European family name doesn't necessarily mean a large share isn't. For example, my own family name is a proper [English surname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennison_(surname)) ... which I got from my Osage paternal grandfather.

Comment: One more example you may want to give is John Kerry (yet another secretary of state); contrary to appearances, his ancestry is not Irish but (half)  Bohemian-Jewish (his grandfather has changed his last name from Kohn to Kerry after immigrating to the US).